# Unable to change shortcut for switching input languages

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages

Whilst upgrading a lot of packages at once and being asked for a bunch of config options, I mistakenly set the shortcut for switching input languages to the shift key. Obviously this was a terrible choice.

When I go into the settings and try to change it, I can't. The checkbox for "shift" is not ticked, so I can't untick it. Ticking the checkbox for another key combination doesn't help because it just adds the new one and doesn't remove the shift one. It's as if the settings app doesn't know that the shift key is set.

Any ideas how I can remove it? Thanks

EDIT: I've tried uninstalling all languages except English. But when I install them again the problem just comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Use regedit to go to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Toggle`.

If you see there any items named "Hotkey", "Language Hotkey" or
"Layout Hotkey", delete them and reboot.

On my computers there are no items under the `Toggle` key.
So if you have more than the above three you may delete them.

This should get rid of all the input languages shortcuts.

You could also export the `Toggle` key to a file, for safe-keeping before
deleting its items.

Answer (score 0):

Might this help?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030418/how-to-change-text-entry-in-ubuntu-18-04/1030433#1030433

It might differ a bit though, check these:

Settings > Region and Language > Add a language *(I'm currently not able to do so!?)*

Settings > Keyboard shortcuts > Super+Space / S+Shift+Space *(= Next / Previous Source)*

Comment: Thanks, but that was already set. Super+Space also works to change the input. But pressing the space key continues to do so as well. My aim is to stop the space key from changing languages

Comment: To remove space; Settings > Keyboard shortcuts >  should be the place to look it up and remove it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and I also tried dconf-editor, dconf on the command line, gsettings on the command line, manually editing xml files... tried everything. In the end I installed a different desktop environment, which finally got rid of it.

Thanks for your help - I agree your answer *should* have worked, but something was clearly very wrong in my case!

Answer (score 0):

Install "Gnome Tweaks".

`Keyboard & Mouse` -> `Keyboard` -> `Additional Layout Options`

and change from Shift to whatever you like.
I made exactly the same mistake and soon it was driving me nuts!